# How to force Eclipse to restart an app that has not changed

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there a way to force Eclipse to restart an Android app that has not changed, even if it has to be re-downloaded and reinstalled?

I am in a situation where I'm running an Android app that does stuff on startup that I need to repeat for debugging purposes.

What I would like to do is click the "Run" button in Eclipse and have it force restart my app each time.  But instead, Eclipse/Android tries to be smart and it just brings my app to the front without restarting.  I get a message in the console:

```
ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

The only workaround I have found is to make dummy text changes to force a recompile/re-install.  But that's kind of annoying, especially with the code under revision control.

Comment: did you try to uninstall the application from the emulator and run again ?

Comment: @PrakashkumarThiagarajan I'm hoping to do this in one-click, see other comments.  Uninstalling an app is rather painful and I need to start/restart the app frequently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lazy work is to put a space char , save it, delete the char, save it and rebuild. As i said the lazy (fast) work..

Comment: I agree this seems like the easiest approach (minimum clicks)

Comment: You'd think there's be an option for this...  but this is what I do, too. :)

Comment: Wow. I guess this kind of thinking was thought up by the same guy that made the Android interface so very usable. Someone has to make a hack to make Eclipse work better?

Comment: agree with jonny... this is ridiculous.

Answer (score 6):

Besides already mentioned meaningless chars and stopping from device menu, you can also stop your application process from DDMS perspective, Devices View -> Name of your process -> push red button.

Comment: OK. Too bad that still requires several clicks.  I was hoping for the ideal, one-click solution of hitting the "Run" button in Eclipse and having it do what I want.  Maybe somebody knows how to suggest changes to Eclipse? (or maybe this is an Android plugin issue)

Comment: @jfritz42 Ideal solution will be to add such option to run configuration of an android app, but, at least for now, there no such option

Comment: It's been a long time since I used Eclipse but maybe you could hook up a keystroke or a script or similar to use instead of that Build and go button.

Answer (score 1):

Kill the app from the running tasks either on the emulator or on the device you are debugging on.

Comment: Settings --> Applications --> Manage Applications --> Your app Name --> Force Stop (or even uninstall)

Comment: I guess my goal is to minimize clicks.  The ideal, one-click solution is just to hit the "Run" button in Eclipse, but that doesn't work.  It seems the next easiest solution is the standard "hit space, delete, save, run"

Comment: Outside of Android I don't use eclipse much but I'm sure you could script something similar to run every time you hit the run button if you are really looking to minimize clicks.